# How to save a list of all files in a directory in a single text file and add prefixes and suffixes?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to save a list of files in a directory into a single file using

```
ls > output.txt
```

Let's say we have in the directory:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

I want to modify the names of these files in the `output.txt` to be like:

```
1a.txt$
1b.txt$
1c.txt$
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. Are tryng to just add a "1" (or whatever) prefix to all lines in a file? (In which case, question is not related at all to directories. It just happen to be how you generated your file). Or are you trying to rename files? (in which case, you don't really need to write the list in a file.

Comment: To add '1' to all lines of a file you could for example ```ls | sed 's/^/1/' > output.txt```

Comment: @chrslg I also want to modify the end of the each line. How do I do that. I have updated the question.

Comment: ```ls | sed 's/^/1/;s/$/$/' > output.txt```

Comment: incidentally, *why* are you trying to do this?  It might well be easier to solve this at the consumer end

Comment: Note that the 1st $ in my additional sed parameter is a special char for sed, meaning "end of line", exactly like "^" meant "beginning of line". Where as the second $ is just a $. 'sed s/A/B/' replace pattern A with B. Pattern A (regular expression) can contains special characters, such as ^ for beginning of line or $ for beginning of line. So here, I replace and empty string at the beginning of line by string 1, which means adding 1 at the beginning of the line. And replace an empty string at the end ot line by string "$", which means adding "$" at the end

Comment: I agree with @2e0byo. Which is the reason why I reply in comments for now, instead of a proper answer. If your question had been "how to add a prefix and a suffix to each line of a file", then I would have replied with the sed solution (which is one among many). But you involved filenames in the question, which make it looks like an XY problem. Reason why I started to ask what is the real question.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way use AWK to change content and save to file via .tmp

This script will print content how you want. Just add "1" and "$" to begining and ending accordingly.

```
cat output.txt  | awk '{print "1"$1"$"}'
```

And then you can save to original file as you want by extending command && (if success then next )

```
cat output.txt  | awk '{print "1"$1"$"}' > output.txt.tmp && mv output.txt.tmp output.txt
```

Comment: Please don't advertise piping the output of *cat* into a command that allows so specify an input file name.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/sh -x
for f in *.txt
do
nf=$(echo "${f}" | sed 's@^@1@')
mv -v "${f}" "${nf}"
done
```

Comment: *modify the names of these files **in the output.txt***, not in the file system.